# Aligning table cells at a specific decimal without affecting headers and empty cells

Tags: tables, alignment

### My code and output:

```
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{| r r@{.}l r@{.}l |} 
  \hline
  & col&1 & col&2\\
  row 1 & $1\,234$&$567\,891(2)$ & $123$&$4(5.6)$ \\
  row 2 & $1\,234$&$567\,891\,2(34)$ & $123$&$456\,789\,12(3)$ \\
  row 3 & & & $12$&$345\,6(7)$\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### The Problem:

I want to align my table cells at the decimal. Since these are accompanied by uncertainties (and some of those have additional decimals, eg the first row of column 2), I want to be able to manually pick the specific decimal that will be used to align the column. This means that I can't use something automatic like `dcolumn`, at least as far as I can tell.

I'm currently using [this](https://ryanmlayer.wordpress.com/2009/10/05/aligning-on-decimal-points-an-example-of-the-specifier/) trick, which works fine but has two problems:

- I need to be able to exclude my headers from this (ie I could like each header to be `c` and to correspond to two columns that are `r@{.}l`. `multicolumn` doesn't seem to work for this use case, because it requires all its columns to have the same alignment (so I can't apply `r@{.}l`).
- I have some cells that will remain empty (like the last one in column 1). Is there a way to get rid of the decimal, ie to have a different descriptor than the rest of the column?

I'll happily accept answers with different solutions than this approach of course, as long as they give me the intended result!

Comment: I'd recommend to use `siunitx` for number columns. However you should be able to use `\multicolumn{2}{c}{col1}`, `\multicolumn{2}{c|}{col2}` and similar for empty cells. So please show a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) of what you've tried and use it to explain your problem with that try, so we can reproduce it without adding guessed code.

Comment: BTW: I recommend not to use vertical lines in tables. Horizontal lines can be improved using package `booktabs`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like this perhaps--

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tabular}{r *2{D{.}{.}{12}}} 
        \toprule
                    &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{col 1}}                      & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{col2}}\\ \midrule
        row 1   & 1\,234.567\,891(2)                & 123.4(5.6) \\
        row 2   & 1\,234.567\,891\,2(34)        & 123.456\,789\,12(3)\\
        row 3   &                                               & 12.345\,6(7)\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

As [@cabohah suggested in comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/712916/aligning-table-cells-at-a-specific-decimal-without-affecting-headers-and-empty-c#comment1771888_712916), I'd use [`siunitix`](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx?lang=en) features (so you do not need to pre-massage the numbers; `siunitx` has a lot of options to do that alone...):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\sisetup{table-alignment-mode = marker, group-minimum-digits = 0}
\begin{tabular}{SSS}
    \toprule
          & col1            & col2 \\
    \midrule
    row 1 & 1234.567891(2)  & 123.4(5.6) \\
    row 2 & 1234.5678912(34)& 123.45678912(3) \\
    row 3 &                 & 12.3456(7) \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(don't look at the relative size of the lines in the screenshot, `okular` has a quite *interesting* antialiasing...)

Answer (score 3):

I don't see an issue using:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{dcolumn}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{| r r@{.}l r@{.}l |} 
  \hline
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{col1} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{col2}\\\hline
  row 1 & $1\,234$&$567\,891(2)$ & $123$&$4(5.6)$ \\
  row 2 & $1\,234$&$567\,891\,2(34)$ & $123$&$456\,789\,12(3)$ \\
  row 3 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & $12$&$345\,6(7)$\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However you also can use something more tricky like:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{dcolumn}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{| r r@{.}l r@{.}l |} 
  \hline
  & col & 1 & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \phantom{0(0.0}\makebox[0pt][r]{col.2} \\\hline
  row 1 & $1\,234$&$567\,891(2)$ & $123$&$4(5.6)$ \\
  row 2 & $1\,234$&$567\,891\,2(34)$ & $123$&$456\,789\,12(3)$ \\
  row 3 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & $12$&$345\,6(7)$\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using `booktabs` and `siunitx` within `tabularray`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\begin{document}
  
  \begin{tblr}{colspec={@{}
        l
        S[table-format = 3.8(1.1), separate-uncertainty, table-align-uncertainty=false]
        S[table-format = 3.8(1.1), separate-uncertainty]
        S[table-format = 2.8(1)]
        @{}},
      row{1} = {guard,font=\bfseries}
      } 
    \toprule
          &      col 1       &     col 2       &     col 3      \\ \midrule
    row 1 & 1234.567891(2)   & 123.4(5.6)      & 123.4(5.6)     \\
    row 2 & 1234.5678912(34) & 123.45678912(3) & 123.45678912(3)\\
    row 3 &                  & 12.3456(7)      & 12.3456(7)     \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tblr}
  
\end{document}
```

The decimal uncertainty can be problematic…

[image]